# Disabling Client-Initiated SSL Renegotiation in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jboss7.x, java-7

**Setting up the context:**
In java 8 (precisely [8b98](https://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8017049)), in order to deal with **Client-Initiated Renegotiation** causing vulnerability to Denial of Service attack, an un-documented flag was rolled out named **jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation** as a part of Transport Layer Security which could disable client initiated renegotiations.

```
jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation = true
```

Server which i'm using is JBoss 7.1.1 which supports 7. However java 8 supporting servers are JBoss EAP & Wildfly. I'm reluctant to switch to these new server.
Now My challenge is to implement this property somehow in Java 7. Any sort of guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution to this problem?.

Comment: @codechefvaibhavkashyap did you get the solution ??

Comment: @Rohitesh Nope.

Comment: @Rohitesh I just posted an answer, hoping this helps.

Comment: @PavanDittakavi I just posted an answer, hoping this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Java 7 doesn't support this option. Maybe an acceptable behavior could be the *Interoperable mode* as in [Description of Phase 2 Fix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#descPhase2) of the JSSE 7, which means enabling renegotiation for "good" clients ?

My exact answer is to switch to OpenSSL implementation, particularly the one with the hard-coded renegotiation denial, then you get rid of the JSSE implementation which doesn't support your hard-to-find option.

First, you need [OpenSSL 0.9.8l](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20091111.txt) which just denies all client renegotiations.
After that enable the [Native Connectors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin%20Guide.html#8094211_AdminGuide-NativeConnectors) on JBOSS 7.1 and configure as said in this documentation.

web archive links :

- http://web.archive.org/web/20201019212829/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20201027040002/https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20091111.txt
- http://web.archive.org/web/20201123225554/https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin%20Guide.html